# Redirect an URL with Wordpress permalinks

Tags: url, redirect, domain-name

I currently have a Wordpress.com blog and will do my own website.

I have some files I want them to keep the same URL.

My question is, how can I configure my website (PHP?) so once online it will use the same kind of permalinks than Wordpress?

Another question, if I change my domain name, do the redirection will affect precise URLs such as www.domainname.com/aze/123 to point to the new domain name?

Comment: Well you’ll need to set up some rewriting, so that those URLs get handled by your script - and then your script has to perform the task of looking up the corresponding content. // If you change your domain name, then you first of all will have to keep the old domain running and under your control, so that you can rewrite the incoming requests to the new domain ...

Comment: In the first case, I have to write a script that will copy Wordpress permalinks?

And for the second one, do rewriting the incoming requests will take into account the more precise URLs like www.domainname.com/aze/123 ?

Comment: Dunno, depends on what exactly you want to achieve ... you said you wanted to keep “files”, but it doesn’t sound like you are talking about _actual_ files here. If you have a lists of WP posts with specific slugs, then you should probably extract those slugs first, yes …

Comment: And taking into account those “more precise” URLs - depends on how you set up the rewriting. Usually one would just rewrite any incoming request to the new domain, keeping the original path and query string component - and handle everything else (like URLs that don’t exist any more, and therefor now need to be answered with a 404/410) in the “new” system.